# PHP - echo data from tables using their relationship

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day :)

I have 2 tables - one containing the main headings and another which contains the subheadings and related paragraphs, which are related with a foreign key on TitleID and LinkID as shown here:

[image]

The idea is that I create a number of divs containing the main titles - from sectionamain with the related subcontent from sectiona, linked thru LinkID and TitleID.

```
<?php
function confirm_query($result_set) {
        if (!$result_set) {
            die("Database query failed.");
        }
    }


function get_practices() {
    global $connection;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM sectionamain ";
    $query .= "LEFT JOIN sectiona ";
    $query .= "ON sectiona.HeadingID = sectionamain.TitleID ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY sectionamain.TitleID ASC";
    $A_list = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($A_list);
    return $A_list;    
}



function display_practices() {
    $output = "<div class=\"container inner\">\n";
   $A_set = get_practices();
   while ($list_A = mysqli_fetch_assoc($A_set)) {
     $output .= "<div class=\"info\">\n";
   $output .= "<div class=\"wrap\">\n";
       $output .= "<h1 class=\"showcontent\" id=";
       $output .= "". htmlentities($list_A["TitleID"]) ."";
       $output .= ">";       
       $output .= htmlentities($list_A["MainTitle"]);
       $output .= "</h1>\n";
       $output .= "<div class=\"content\" id=\"content".htmlentities($list_A["TitleID"]) ."\">\n";

       *** code would go here - 
       put items from sectiona with LinkID = 1 where TitleID = 1, etc until all data is sorted 
         $output .="</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n";   

    };
     mysqli_free_result($A_set);
    $output .= "</div>\n";
       return $output;
}
?>

The end result would be something as shown below: 
<h1>Main Title 1</h1>
<h3>Sub 1 with LinkID 1<h1>
<h3> ... </h3>
<h3>Sub n with LinkID 1</h3>

... 
<h1>Main Title n</h1>
<h3>Sub 1 with LinkID n<h1>
<h3> ... </h3>
<h3>Sub n with LinkID n</h3>
```

Thank you in advance
xx

Comment: Thank you for sharing your story! Is there an actual question as well, or did you just want to update us on your progress?

Comment: Whats the issue ?

Comment: Apologies  for not being more clear about things  - I need to get the data from the table titled sectiona as subtitles sorted according to titleID.

Comment: Your query is ambiguous in the select statement.  Instead of using the wildcard, notate exactly which fields you want to pull. I'll go ahead and write up an answer.

Comment: Oh, on second thought, that might not be the problem.  It's still good practice to specify which fields you want to access.  Are you able to get *any* results from the DB?

Comment: @TimMorton - I will be using most results from my table.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your grouping issue, it's a matter of creating a data structure in an array.  Since the database will give rows with repeating information, use this repeated information as a key in an array.

```
<?php
function get_practices() {
    global $connection;

    // It's good practice to specify which fields you want to get from the database.
    // for clarity, I'm using heredoc format. 
    $query = >>>SECTIONAQUERY

SELECT am.TitleID, am.MainTitle, a.HeadingID, a.title, a.content  
FROM sectionamain am
LEFT JOIN sectiona a
ON a.HeadingID = am.TitleID 
ORDER BY sectionamain.TitleID ASC

SECTIONAQUERY;

    $A_list = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($A_list);
    return $A_list;    
}

/**
 * group_items 
 *
 * takes database results and groups them by ID
 *
 * @param mysqli_result
 * @return array
 */
function group_items($db_results) {
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_results)) {
    $title_id = htmlentities($row['TitleID']);

    // group Main Title by title id
    $data[$title_id]['title'] = htmlentities($row['MainTitle']);

    // group data by title id
    $data[$title_id]['data'][] = array(
      'HeadingID' => htmlentities($row['HeadingID']),
      'title'     => htmlentities($row['title']),
      'content'   => htmlentities($row['content'])
      );
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Then in your view, you could have something like this:

```
<?php 
$A_list = get_practices();
$data = group_items($A_list);

// or, alternatively, $data = group_items(get_practices());

// now, go into "html mode" instead of in PHP, 
// using PHP only for looping and variable substitution:
?>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
  <div>Your header stuff</div>
  <div class="info">
    <div class="wrap">
      <?php foreach($data as $row): ?>
        <h1 class="showcontent" id="<?= $row['title'] ?>"></h1>
        <?php foreach($row['data'] as $sub_row): ?>
          <h3><?= $sub_row['title'] ?></h3>
          <div class="content"><?= $sub_row['content'] ?></div>

          <!-- bonus: link to a new page? -->
          <div><a href="detail_page.php?id=<?= $sub_row['HeadingID'] ?>"><?= $sub_row['title'] ?></a></div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note, I personally would not stick output into a function; that's mixing logic and presentation.  By using PHP's built-in templating, you don't have to worry about escaping quotes.  Just use the `<?= ?>` syntax to drop in PHP variables. Use an `include` statement instead of calling the function.  (or, you could always have the function `include` a partial view.)

Hope this addressed your question!

Comment: For some reason $row['HeadingID'] is giving me an unidentified index error.

Comment: do a `var_dump($row)` to see what it should be named.  Sounds like a typo.

Comment: I did that and it still gives problems.  But other than that I made it work. :)